# How to split an array of objects in SQL?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have a table in my database which has the following columns:

```
ID        Data
1        [{"na":false,"answer":1.5},{"na":false,"answer":0.5}]
2        [{"na":false,"answer":0.5},{"na":false,"answer":1}]
3        [{"na"":false,"answer":1.5},null]
```

Now, I want to split the data column into two columns in a select statement (which is used elsewhere). The first column Score1 will have the data present in the first object's answer field i.e 1.5 for the ID=1 and the second column Score2 will have the data present in the second object's answer field i.e 0.5 for ID=1, if there is null then the value should be null/0.

The maximum number of scores will be 2 i.e two objects. So, I will need to extract two columns called Score1 and Score2

The result of the select statement should be like this:

select ID, 'some magic happens here' as Score1, 'some magic again' as Score2 from score;

```
ID       Score1      Score2
1        1.5         0.5
2        0.5         1
3        1.5         0/null
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: the answer will differ depending on the database ,which dbms are you using? tag your database

Comment: Every database does that differently.  Are you using SQLite, Oracle, MySQL5.x, MySQL8, SQL Server, etc, etc, etc?

Comment: Also, aiming for each score in a different ***column*** is a SQL Anti-Pattern.  You should be aiming for each score to be on a different ***row***, that's the structure the SQL language is designed to work with, and the structure database engines are optimised for.

Comment: Also double double quote doesn't look like valid json format ex:""answer""

Comment: Im using SQL server. The use case for this is that the table will be used in a powerbi direct query mode. So, I have to do the data transformation in only SELECT statement.

Comment: @the_new_guy - Then you need to define the maximum number of scores you're going to support, and always return that many columns.  Because a simple `SELECT` ***Can Not*** give a dynamic number of columns.

Comment: Hey @MatBailie, the maximum number of scores will be 2.

Comment: Please add this information to the question, not just comments, thanks.

Comment: Done,Sir. Thank you.

Comment: What is the SQL Server version? JSON support was introduced in SQL Server 2016.

Comment: I cant make changes to the column itself, Ill have to make changes to it on the go for my powerbi use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use SQL Server 2016+, you may use `JSON_VALUE()` to parse the stored JSON and extract the values. Note, that the result from `JSON_VALUE()` is a single text value of type `nvarchar(4000)`.

Table:

```
SELECT *
INTO JsonTable
FROM (VALUES
   (1,        '[{"na":false,"answer":1.5},{"na":false,"answer":0.5}]'),
   (2,        '[{"na":false,"answer":0.5},{"na":false,"answer":1}]'),
   (3,        '[{"na":false,"answer":1.5},null]')
) v (ID, Data)
```

Statement:

```
SELECT 
  t.ID, 
  JSON_VALUE(t.Data, '$[0].answer') AS Score1,
  JSON_VALUE(t.Data, '$[1].answer') AS Score2
FROM JsonTable t
```

Result:

```
ID Score1 Score2
------------------
1  1.5    0.5
2  0.5    1
3  1.5
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. Really appreciate your help. Cheers